# Tensorflow not detecting my gpu even with all requisite files installed

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I had tensorflow gpu 2.10 installed and it was working well. I mistakenly decided to upgrade to 2.11 without knowing it doesnt support gpu in windows. So I uninstalled it and reinstalled tensorflow gpu 2.10. Problem is that now it doesnt detect my gpu.

> ```
> import tensorflow as tf
> from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
> from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
> from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
>
> print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
> print(tf.__version__)
> print(tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support())
> ```

The above code gives the output:

> Num GPUs Available:  0
> 2.10.0
> True

So the code detects that I have TF built with gpu support yet its not detecting it. My GPU is GTX960m with CUDA 12.0 and CuDNN 8.7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (might not be the optimal, but is a solution).

It is a mix between these two sites:

https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-and-anaconda-onwindows-2ee9c39b5c44

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

The first one works, but it leaves you with an older version of Tensorflow.

The new configuration should be:

- Python: 3.10
- Microsoft Visual Studio (MSVS): 2019
- CUDA: 11.2
- tensorflow_gpu-2.10.0   (for some reason, I couldn't install 2.11, but 2.10 worked ok)

---

The algorithm is:

1. Install Anaconda (if it is not already installed)
2. Go to Anaconda Prompt, and write:

- conda create --name tf-gpu
- conda activate tf-gpu
- conda install python=3.10
- conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=11.2
- conda install pip
- pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.10

That's it, hope it works (it did for me).

Remember to activate your tf-gpu environment each time you want to use it.